# AWS Code Pipeline root is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm strugeling with one task. I want to create a roles and assigne to them a policy. I'm using .yaml template to creat that. I want to do this via CodePipeline -> I'm choosing there as Deploy action provider a CloudFormation. Everytime when I want to create a pipline I'm receving error: root is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole. Can you help with this?
Here is my template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"


Parameters:
    RolesName:
        Description: Entere role name
        Type: String

Resources:
  RootRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - s3.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: snowflake_access
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: '*'
                Resource: '*'
      RoleName: !Ref RolesName
  RootInstanceProfile:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref RolesName
```

Comment: What is the full error message? Which resource fails? Who is `root`?

Comment: What does the IAM role attached to your CodePipeline look like?

Comment: The Role name resource is failing, I'm doing this in a root account. So basicaly I want to create a template file where I can create a new role and assign the policy to this role. Above u can see a template. Also I want to do this via CodePipeline -> CloudFormation

Answer (score 1):

You have S3 as your Principal, you need to change it to `codepipeline`

```
      Principal:
          Service:
            - codepipeline.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's not helping at all. It's still the same problem :(